# Integer only validation for angularjs ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

How to validate positive integer numbers using `ng-pattern`. Now i have this pattern `^[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]+)?$/`. But it allows decimal values. I need to disallow decimal values too

Comment: ^[0-9]\d*$ try this

Comment: @zabusa no luck\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Simple! Just use **`^\d+$`** *where, decimals won't be allowed*

Answer (score 0):

try this in ng-pattern `^\-?\d+$` and not accept any -values

Answer (score 0):

Positive integers without leading zeros: [`^[1-9]\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/pLhmUS/1)

Answer (score -1):

Use this expression

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"
```

you can check regex on [here](https://regex101.com/)